# Altering all columns in a 2D list

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

I have a 2D list of data which looks something like this:

```
[        0         1
9    0.00  1213.0
10   0.10  1281.0
11   0.20  1281.0
12   0.30  1281.0
13   0.40  1281.0
..    ...       ...
135  12.00       4.0
136  12.10       2.0
137  12.20       2.0
138  12.30       0.0
139  12.40       0.0

[131 rows x 2 columns]]
[        0         1
9    0.00  1283.0
10   0.10  1281.0
11   0.20   111.0
12   0.30   111.0
13   0.40   102.0
..    ...       ...
135  12.00       4.0
136  12.10       2.0
137  12.20       2.0
138  12.30       2.0
139  12.40       2.0

[131 rows x 2 columns]
```

I want to perform an operation on Column 2 by subtracting next element from current element. And I want to print the final 2D list with the new column elements to make it look like the one above. How can I do this?

I tried with df.iloc but I am not able to get the final 2D array. 
The function i use to perform the operation is as follows. data here is a list I made of the 2nd row elements. I wish to perform this without having to make a new list and also on the 2D list.

```
final = [x - y for x, y in zip(data, data[1:])]
```

I want this to work on column to of above data and also give back the 2D list as it is.

Comment: `df.iloc[:,1] = df.iloc[:,1] - df.iloc[:,1].shift(-1)`?

Comment: @QuangHoang It gives me an array as I am dealing with lists.